# When I ran apt-get update, I got the error "...repository... does not have a Release file"

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, 21.04

When I run `apt-get update`, I get the following error message:

```
error:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]

error:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: You get those errors because you added one PPA that has nothing for your release and the other is probably a leftover form a very old release (14.04), EoL since 2019 therefore the repository no longer exists. BTW, you shouldn't mix repositories of different releases.

Answer (score 4):

The PPA [https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/xerus-media](https://launchpad.net/%7Emc3man/+archive/ubuntu/xerus-media) does not have a package for hirsute. It was last updated 3 years ago.

About the following error,

```
error:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main arm64 Packages 404 Not Found
```

How did you get trusty (14.04) repository in 21.04? Mixing repositories in this way can break your installation.

You can remove the ppa with
`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/xerus-media`, and remove the trusty repo from `/etc/apt/sources.list` to fix these error messages.